# Partially refund the authorized order in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to make a partial refund in PayPal v2 SDK but each time the whole amount is captured. I am just capturing the different amount so in this way the rest amount should be dropped, but the full amount is captured no matter I am requesting the partial. Workflow is like this : 1) I am creating order, 2) Authorizing the order, 3) now need to make a partial refund. The code I am using is like below :

```
class CaptureOrder
        {
            public static function buildRequestBody($new_Price_after_refund_requests)
            {
                return array(
                    'intent' => 'AUTHORIZE',
                    'application_context' =>
                        array(
                            'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
                            'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel'
                        ),
                    'purchase_units' =>
                        array(
                            0 =>
                                array(
                                    'amount' =>
                                        array(
                                            'currency_code' => 'USD',
                                            'value' =>  $new_Price_after_refund_requests
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                );
            }

            public static function orderCapture($authorizationId, $new_Price_after_refund_requests)
            {
                $request = new AuthorizationsCaptureRequest($authorizationId);
                $request->headers["prefer"] = "return=representation";
                $request->body = self::buildRequestBody($new_Price_after_refund_requests);
                $response = makeclient()->execute($request);
              if($response->status == "COMPLETED"){
                    //some codes here
            }
                echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                return $response;
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to make a partial refund of authorized order? Maybe this shouldn't be like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request body's fields are incorrect and so are not recognized. Unrecognized fields are ignored. Since everything about your body is being ignored, the original amount is being captured.

To create a body with correct fields, see [the API reference for a v2/payments authorization request](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_capture), which has this sample body (there are other fields in the sample, all are optional):

```json
{
  "amount": {
    "value": "10.99",
    "currency_code": "USD"
  }
}
```

Convert this to PHP array syntax, and use your variable for the value.

---

Your function's name is a bit misleading, by the way. You aren't capturing a PayPal order (doing so would have no authorization step). Rather, you *authorized* an order in the previous step (at checkout time), and are now capturing that *authorization*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have got your point and edited like you said. Interesting  point is that I was thinking that the amount of order will be reduced, however what I see after reduced amount capture request is that it stays as it was like before but paypal sends the amount which I reduced as a new order  to the buyer. is it working like this? Why paypal creates new order for that? why the authorized amount is not reduced? I mean we have already an order why to create new one ?

Comment: If you're referring to what shows up on the customer's funding source, such as a credit card, yes that can happen and the old authorization (for the original amount) will fall off after ~3 days or sometimes up to 10 days. Exact behavior will depend on the country, local laws, and credit card companies involved.

Comment: (And if you're referring to the payer's PayPal.com activity view, it's probably just showing a chronological view of the activity).

Comment: and the amount will be held in that time frame? I mean even though I am capturing reduced amount, user should wait up to 10 days in order to take his amount back? that is so weird.. Because the reason I am using authorization was because to make all these things easier and instant. The frozen amount just could be unfrozen though why user needs to wait such long time ?

Comment: One of the variables you can pass in the body is `"final_capture": "true"`; I'm not sure what the default (maybe false, meaning further captures on the authorization are possible) but doing a final capture might change what's shown in the activity log

Comment: Another thing you can do is contact PayPal's business support and ask them to enable "enhanced authorization and settlement" for the account, which can help to re-use existing authorizations, depending on the country

Comment: customer pays 200$, I want to refund 150$, capturing 50$, and user waits 10 days to get that 150$... absolutely useless if this is what paypal come up with that in 21st century :) And as far as I understand there is no any other way to give that money to customer asap...

Comment: Make sure you are sending final_capture: true if this is a concern. PayPal communicates with credit card companies instantly, but their behavior (how long it takes authorizations to fall off) can vary by country and local laws, and PayPal does not control it